# Utilizar o uma só parâmetro em outras paginas com Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Estou fazendo uma aplicação em *laravel 5.4* que o administrador modifica várias informações de um determinado cliente.

Exemplo: na listagem de clientes é clicado em Módulos 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O usuário é direcionando para outra página, que é ambiente que vai listar, modificar, etc. Todas as informações de cada modulo desse cliente.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porem o meu problema é que estou tendo que ficar passando o `ID` do cliente por todas as páginas, pela *URL*.

Exemplo:

> admin/modulos/1/financeiro/dados  **o '1' é o ID do cliente.**

Ou

> admin/modulos/1/fornecedor/dados **o '1' é o ID do cliente.**

Ia tentar utilizar o *Service Container* do *laravel*, mas não consegui entender como fazer isso na minha aplicação.

Comment: Se poderia explicar melhor a última parte ficou confusa? vale lembrar que isso é normal fazer assim claro vai depender de um contexto melhor, mas, se puder esclarecer a ultima parte !!!

Comment: Gostaria de passar o parâmetro uma unica vez, tipo quando vou abrir a pagina de um modulo tenho que pegar o parâmetro do ID do cliente, isso vai ocorrer em todas as pagina dos módulos. li algo sobre singleton, mas não consegui entender como implementar isso.

Comment: Vamos ver se eu entendi, aquela aba você vai clicando e vai passando uma apos a outra com um endereço ? e nesse endereço é carregado a pagina novamente e tem aquele id que tanto te incomoda a ser passado?

Comment: isso! igual **admin/modulos/1/financeiro** é um modulo **admin/modulos/1/fornecedor** outro modulo, cada um é uma aba diferente.

Comment: é assim mesmo não tem forma melhor, você vai criar um singleton para que, se vai criar uma sessão ou um cookie para que, se o elemento na url já o satisfaz e não consome recursos. na minha experiência é assim mesmo ...

Comment: Porque você não melhorar a interface e carrega essas informações logo de cara?

Comment: Pensei em fazer isso, mas são bastante módulos, a pagina vai ficar imensa, e demorar muito pra carregar

Comment: achei que teria outra forma de fazer isso, sem precisar de ficar passando o parâmetro do ID o tempo todo na URL

Comment: Entendi cara ... bom eu acho que não é necessário fazer outra coisa diferente ... mas, sei lá! cada um tem a sua experiência e opinião ...

Comment: Ok! Obrigado mesmo assim. acho que vou continuar a mesma forma que estou fazendo mesmo!

Comment: Mostre como está a rota que você está definindo, e o método do controlador.

Comment: rota    `Route::get('{cid}/financeiro', ['as' => 'financial.index', 'uses' => 'MfinancialController@index']);`

Comment: Controller `public function index($cid)
    {
        $client = $this->userRepository->find($cid);

        return view('admin.modules.financial.index', compact('client'));
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Cara uma forma de vc implementar isso que esta querendo é passar o id pela sessão

```
session(['cliente'=>'valor do id']);
```

e no final do ultimo modulo quando ele for salvar você pode utilizar

```
$id = session()->pull('cliente');
```

esse metodo **pull()** ira tirar cliente da sessão e passar para o **$id**

Comment: Mas eu consigo mudar essa session['cliente'] qualquer hora?  tipo quando vou clicar no Módulo do segundo cliente ele já vai atribuir um novo valor para a session['cliente'] ??

Comment: sim, se vc chamar essa funcao no metodo que inicia o modulo .

Comment: `public function index($id)
    {
        session(['cid' => $id]);
        $client_Id = session()->pull('cid');

        //  dd($client_Id);
        $client = $this->userRepository->find($client_Id);
        return view('admin.modules.index', compact('client'));
    }`

Comment: fiz assim mas quando foi em uma outra janela buscar a session, não veio o valor, Poderia me dar um exemplo??

Comment: Implementar pela sessão não é a forma correta de resolver o problema. 
Se o usuário abrir por exemplo duas janelas, uma para cada cliente, você via ter problemas.

Comment: é nesse caso do varias janelas não daria certo , oque poderia fazer é utilizar um verificação para caso ja tenha o cliente na sessão ele não iria alterar continuaria com o mesmo

Comment: é descartei essa ideia.